# How to define a table to calculate discounts on bills

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table to calculate discounts on bills for sale manager depend on total price for a customer.

example:

if `total_price` equal `100$`, the discount will be `0`.

if `total_price` between `100$` and `200$`, the discount will be `0.02%`.

if `total_price` between `200$` and `300$`, the discount will be `0.04%`.
and so on.

how can I create a correct schema to this purpose?

Comment: create a `discount_rules` table containing your rules. Retrieve this information in your invoicing application and apply the rules with an applicative business engine.

Comment: of course. can you help me to make correct schema?

Comment: Storing json objects in a database table is considered an anti-pattern but if your rules can change (as in: getting additional specifications) then it might be a good idea to store each rule as json object in a record. You'd then just parse and apply the json object in the application.

Comment: Well creating a database and a table is nothing special. I suppose you could start with a few columns such as `price_from`, `price_to`, `discount_percent`

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with three columns: lower, upper and discount.
Given a value you can query the table like this:
select discount from your_table where lower < value and value <= upper